# Ubuntu Destkop Share File Transfer

Tags: vnc

im trying to findout some informations about the desktop share built-in application since im newbie to it and also to the entire linux so :

i have turned on the vino for some time and i also gave a password to it , but i have heard that it has already happend that someone has guessed the password and then he has gained an access to your machine , now even if someone would guess my password right , is there any way for that stranger-hacker to transfer all my source codes or files to his machine instantly ? for example team viewer allows so basicaly if someone connects to you can he directly copy your files to his machine ? in other words steal them?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing), the VNC system does not necessarily support direct file transfers. I cannot find any information suggesting that `vino` supports file transfers, so my guess would be that **no, it would not be possible for someone accessing your computer via VNC to transfer files directly from your machine via VNC**. However, I do not believe this would stop someone accessing your desktop remotely from initiating something other than `vino` in order to steal your files.

Answer (score 0):

If someone gains access to your computer by guessing vino's password, they can do whatever they like to your system, including deleting all your files because they will gain the same access you have when you are using your system **BUT**...

In order for this to happen, certain prerequisits have to co-exist which would not be accidental:

1. The hacker attack has to originate from your local network because unless you have specifically configured vino to open the port vnc connections are using on your router, using **UPnP**, no contact can be made to vino from the internet.
2. There is one more option in vino settings that allows the remote user to have full access or just view the desktop.  This option has to be enabled too.
3. One third option asks you whether you want to allow a remote user to connect automatically if they know the correct password or have vino inform you about the connection attempt so that you can approve it manually.

They cannot transfer files using vino itself but as you can understand, this is probably the least of the problems they could create.  If you are very, very, unlucky and they guess your account password too so that they can use `sudo`, well...  that would mean more problems, like installing software on your system for example.

Comment: thanks , this is the best asnwer i have ever seen here on the so , and i didnot know about that UPnP option thats cool i was disabled all the time and of course i have checked the checbox which said i have to manually aproove finally i know something about the vino

Comment: You're welcome.  Please check the answer as accepted if it worked for you.  Thanks.  ;-)